# How can I move an Win 8.1 GPT EFI installation to a smaller disk?

Tags: windows-8, boot, partitioning, gpt, efi

which programs do you use to move a whole HDD (GPT EFI Win8.1 installation with the "boot" and "reserved" partition) to a (~10MB) smaller one?

I tried "mini tool partition wizard" and "gparted live" but both seem to not know the filesystem or flags of the "reserved" partition. "mini tool partition wizard", I think, even mixes up the GUID values of the partitions, making Win 8.1 not able to start anymore.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What tools have you tried?  There are dozens of options.

Comment: "mini tool partition wizard" and "gparted live". Both dont seem to be working with Win8.1 partitions. I want to know if someone did successfully such a move of Win8.1 and the tool they used.

Comment: @pythonimus: Do you have already find a solution? I got the same question

Comment: No. I reinstalled Windows and moved the files manually. If I manually fiddle around with the partitions Windows does weird things.